# react click handler does not work properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

there is a click handler , with 2 statements, and just one of them works, and when I comment out one of them , the other one works properly.
the setShowDeleteConfirm is local state . and the setDeleteModal is context.
why this happens?. tanx in advance.

```
<FaTrashAlt onClick={(e) => {
          setShowDeleteConfirm(!showDeleteConfirm);
          setDeleteModal(!deleteModal);
          e.stopPropagation();
          
          }}/>
```

Comment: So, in order to make sure our state is updated based on previous state value, I have used function as an argument to `setState()`, Please try now :) Hope this helps. And regarding `e.preventPropagation()`, I believe that is not needed at all.

Comment: @ImranRafighRather tanx man , I moved the properties of the local state (setShowDeleteConfirm(!showDeleteConfirm)  to that context and It's working now. but I couldn't solve the issue the way they were

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is that `setState()` is asynchronous in Nature, we do not know when one will be executed. That's why this happens.

Suppose you have these two set Functions.

```
  setShowDeleteConfirm(!showDeleteConfirm);
  setDeleteModal(!deleteModal);
```

When the  `setShowDeleteConfirm(!showDeleteConfirm);` starts to execute, we cannot predict when it would update the state,  as this is asynchronous in nature, the same goes with other case.
Cheers !!!

One quick solution I feel is to use callback within the Hook.

```
<FaTrashAlt onClick={(e) => {
          setShowDeleteConfirm( (prevState) =>{
               return {
                    showDeleteConfirm:!prevState
               }
           } );
          setDeleteModal( (prevState) => {
                return{
                deleteModal:!prevState
               });
           }
          e.stopPropagation(); // I feel this should not be used, it has no purpose here.
          
          }}/>
```

Comment: @ImranRagiqRather , tanx sir, so how would you fix this kind of issue to execute both of them?

Comment: Hmmm, Nice Question. Now comes the challenge, I assume my assumption for this is right. But I may be wrong also as I am a human. 

So, how to cross check this and solve this would depend on what code you have written dear Friend. :) 

Do you know about Codesandbox? I would suggest you create a project there with the same scenario and add the components needed to tackle this issue, especially I would like to know what we are trying to achieve :)

Comment: @february7 Wait, let me think a quick solution, If that works we do not need to create a codesandbox project. And dear Friend, I am no `Sir`. We are friends.

Answer (score 0):

When you are updating the state based on previous value it is always better to use the functional pattern. This helps us with a predictable value for the previous state.

```
 <FaTrashAlt onClick={(e) => {
          setShowDeleteConfirm( showDeleteConfirm => !showDeleteConfirm);
          setDeleteModal( deleteModal => !deleteModal);
          e.stopPropagation();
          
          }}/>
```